# SELECT MAX(trans_id),Bank_state,`Forwarded_to` FROM `t_support_details`

Tags: mysql

```
Trans_id    Bank_State  forwarded_to
70           15             1
71           16             2
```

---

```
SELECT MAX(trans_id)
     , Bank_state
     , Forwarded_to 
  FROM t_support_details
```

is giving me result

```
MAX(trans_id)  Bank_state  forwarded_to
           71          16             1
```

But Result should be

```
MAX(trans_id)  Bank_state  forwarded_to
           71          16             2
```

Please help me

Comment: are you using mysql or oracle?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t_support_details ORDER BY trans_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: MySql.why dont we use Max function?? Can u tell please

Comment: That's a different question. If the answer provided within the manual is inadequate, then by all means, ask another question.

Comment: @MadhusudhanReddy:- Why you need to use Max? The result which you have pasted can be achieved without it. Also if there is anything else which you are looking for then you need to edit your question and add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM t_support_details 
ORDER BY trans_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, Simple and easy

```
SELECT *
FROM t_support_details 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT MAX(trans_id) FROM t_support_details 
    )
```

As you are looking for the row having maximum trans_id , so its better to use where clause in this particular scenario than the way you are trying to achieve the required output :D.

Comment: 'better' than what? 'better' in what sense?